# Singleton уровня запроса в ClassLibrary

Tags: asp.net-mvc, веб-сервер, asp.net-web-api

Передо мной стоит задача перебросить расчётную часть десктопного проекта на сервер (asp.net mvc; связь через api сервис). При этом возможности глубокой переработки кода нет.

Проблема следующая: в десктопном приложении существовал Класс взаимосвязей - большой статический класс, на который были завязаны все алгоритмы. То есть он был виден отовсюду (он же статический и выполняется на клиенте).

Сейчас мне надо реализовать его на сервере. Но статику я применить не смогу (так как в этом случае к нему будут обращаться и изменять все потоки, а мне нужно, чтобы он был уникальным для одного расчёта). Плюс логика расчёта вынесена в отдельную ClassLibrary.

Кто-нибудь знает механизм как сделать внутри classLibrary класс, который был бы уникальным для расчёта, но при этом к нему можно было бы обратиться из любого места кода? Такой singleton на время жизни одного запроса.

Comment: на Core такое легко делается, через встроенный Dependency Injection, настраивается время жизни в один запрос

Comment: Увы, переехать на Core нет возможности

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо ваш класс хранить в `HttpContext.Items`, эта коллекция хранит значения в течении одного запроса.

Написать функцию, например так

```
public static MyClass GetMyClassFromHttpContext() {
   if(HttpContext.Current.Items["myKey"] == null) {
      // создание класса
   } 
   return HttpContext.Current.Items["myKey"];
}
```

`HttpContext.Current` это текущий контекст.

Заметим что эта функция доступна из любого места кода.